# Какую систему контроля версий удобнее использовать в данном случае?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте!

Стоит Visual Studio и хотелось бы поставить локальную систему контроля версий, которая есть только у меня на компе. Что в этом случае удобнее использовать и знаете ли вы какие-нибудь ссылки на гайды как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вводные статьи: [система управления версиями для Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171339(v=vs.90).aspx). Удобно использовать: [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) с помощью плагина [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) либо [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) и [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_ru/)

Answer (score 1):

В качестве локальной VCS разумно использовать Git. Городить огород с svn в вашем случае совершенно излишне.
 Попробуйте вот этот комплект:  [gitextensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/). Он достаточно универсален, включает в себя windows версию git и расширения для студии. Так-же в наличии видеоруководства по работе. А  [вот тут](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/tools/Git.xml)  расписано как ставить.

[Сравнение с svn обсуждалось](http://www.askdev.ru/question/1703/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-Git-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-Subversion/) на дружественном сайте.